# how to create a vector of possible values in the arguments of a function

Tags: r, time-series

I wrote a function, to make Regression on embedded time series. Now I can regress on three lags. I would like to expand arguments of the function to select up to how many lags to use. So, the argument should be a vector and if I specify `c(1,NA,1)` then it should use lag =1 and 3, without lag =2. How can I do it? TS is just a vector of numbers.

```
my_function<-function(TS,horizon){

  embed_TS               <- embed(TS,(horizon+3))
  my_length              <- dim(embed_TS)[1]
  time                   <- c(1:my_length)
  last_actual            <- tail(TS,3)
  last_actuals           <-data.frame(last_actual)

  direct       <- rep(0,horizon)
  limit_95     <- vector("list",horizon)
  my_fit       <- rep(0,horizon)

  for(i in 1:horizon)
  {
    x   <- embed_TS[,(1+i)]
    x2  <- embed_TS[,(2+i)]
    x3  <- embed_TS[,(3+i)]
    z   <-time
    my_fit.lm       <- lm(embed_TS[,1] ~ x+x2+x3+z)
    direct[i]       =c(1, last_actual,(my_length+i)) %*% coef(my_fit.lm)
    pred_int        =data.frame(x=last_actuals[1,1],x2=last_actuals[2,1],x3=last_actuals[3,1],z=(my_length+i))
    limit_95[[i]]   =predict(my_fit.lm, pred_int, interval = "prediction",level=0.95)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does `c(1,NA,1)` correspond to lags 1 & 2? It's not obvious what the question is asking, I'm afraid. Providing a way of generating data, or a sample would help. Pointing out the lag part of this function with in code comments would also be great.

Comment: it was misprint, I changed it, c(1,NA,1) correspond to lags 1 & 3